# Static library in Xcode 7 / iOS9

Tags: static-libraries, xcode7

I wrote a code to create a library named 'libHashUtils.a' in Xcode 7/iOS 9 and compile the code. But I am not able to figure it out where it is. It shows me in the Xcode as follows:

[image]

Please let me know the setting so that ti can get 'libHashUtils.a' in 'Products'

Comment: It'll be in your `DerivedData` folder (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<someprojectname>`).  You might find it useful to create a `~/tmp` directory and set all the Xcode output folders to that, to make this stuff easier to find.

Comment: @trojanfoe I did not get you.

Comment: @trojanfoe I got it.